# Removing the 'SEQUENCE' table

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm using the jpa just for fetch data from the db, is it possible doing it without adding the SEQUENCE table to the db?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

I believe you are referring to a table that has been created because an entity is using [Table Sequencing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Table_sequencing).  Also see [GenerationType](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html) Enum.

If you use **GenerationType.IDENTITY** for all your entities then you should not need a sequence table, as it would use the tables autoincrement feature on most databases.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html

Comment: The user can only use IDENTITY *if* the database supports such a concept as autoincrement, serial etc.